# rake aborted! can't convert nil into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift

rake aborted! Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: can't convert nil into Hash

I am trying to deploy ruby on rails on openshift, and then i try to run rake db:migrate. Then i face this problem.

I create the app with https://github.com/kohjx/TestYourCode.git on openshift with ruby on rails + mysql 5.1

Then i configure the config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  #adapter: sqlite3
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: "<%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME']%>"
  username: "<%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME']%>"
  password: "<%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD']%>"
  host:     <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST']%>
  port:     <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT']%>



development:
  <<: *default
  #database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  #database: db/test.sqlite3
  database: testyourcode_test

production:
  <<: *default
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  #database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I setup the RAILS_ENV=development, but i can't figure out how to solve. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what rake task are you running when you get the error?

Comment: He said `rake db:migrate`

Comment: xD totally missed that. my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance it looks like you're using the Openshift DB as your default and then all your Rails environments are using that default setup. Your local machine (where I'm assuming you're running the `rake db:migrate`) isn't able to use those connection details to the OPenshift DB.

Instead of having the Openshift DB configuration in the default section move it down to the production setting and switch the RAILS_ENV=production with `rhc set-env RAILS_ENV=production`. Then configure the development with settings that your localmachine can use. After thats all done, try running your db:migrate once more.

Comment: Thanks, I solve it. it is the secret_key_base problem in the secret.yml. The database.yml is very concern about indentation too.